# How to check was function called or not in C?

Tags: c, function

I am working with files and I want to check, whether function fprintf has written info in the file or not (I check if the result of funct. != 0), but each time I check it it calls function fprtinf what I don't need.

How can I check it?

Here is my code:

How do you check a function is called or not?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define SIZE 5

int main(void) 
{
  char univ [64] = "KPI";
  char department [64] = "APEPS";
  char group_index [16] = "TR-14";
  char surname [32] = "Ivanov";
  int variant_number = 8;


  bool locker1 = true;
  bool locker2 = true;

  int c;

  FILE *file = fopen("text.bak", "w+");

  if (file == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!\n");   
      return 1;             
   }
   else if (file != NULL)
   {
     printf("File was successfully created!\n"); 
   }


  fprintf(file, "%s, dep %s, group %s, %s, var № %d.", univ, department, group_index, surname, variant_number);

   while (fprintf(file, "%s, dep %s, group %s, %s, var № %d.", univ, department, group_index, surname, variant_number != 0) && locker1 == true)
       {
         printf("Info was written successfully\n");
         locker1 = false;
       }
  fprintf(file, "\n\nMatrix of numbers: \n");


  int twoDimArray [SIZE][SIZE];

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
      twoDimArray[i][j] = rand() % 50 - 1;

      fprintf(file, " %d ", twoDimArray[i][j]);
       while (fprintf(file, " %d ", twoDimArray[i][j]) != 0 && locker2 == true)
       {
         printf("Matrix of numbers has been written sucessfully.");
         locker2 = false;
       }
    }
    fprintf(file, "\n");
  }

  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Save `fprintf` result `int res = fprintf(...);` then check with `if (res)` and you will about that second call that you do not need.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento `if (res)` isn't quite right because `fprintf` returns a negative value on failure or the number of characters written on success.